# Using Provider in Widget's initState or initialising life-cycle

Tags: flutter, dart, lifecycle, flutter-provider, flutter-widget

So while learning Flutter, it seems that `initState()` is not a place to use Providers as it does not yet have access to `context` which must be passed. The way my instructor gets around this is to use the `didChangeDependencies()` life-cycle hook in conjunction with a flag so that any code inside doesn't run more than once:

```dart
bool _isInit = true;

@override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (_isInit) {
      // Some provider code that gets/sets some state
    }
    _isInit = false;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

This feels like a poor development experience to me. Is there no other way of running initialisation code within a Flutter Widget that has access to `context`? Or are there any plans to introduce something more workable?

The only other way I have seen is using `Future.delayed` which feels a bit "hacky":

```dart
@override
  void initState() {
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero).then(() {
      // Some provider code that gets/sets some state 
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to schedule code to run at the end of the current frame. If scheduled within `initState()`, it seems that the Widget is fully setup by the time the code is running.

To do so, you can use the [addPostFrameCallback](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/addPostFrameCallback.html) method of the `SchedulerBinding` instance:

```dart
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      // Some provider code that gets/sets some state 
    })
  }
```

You can also use `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback()` for this. They both behave the same for the purpose of running code once after the Widget has been built/loaded, but [here](https://medium.com/flutterworld/flutter-schedulerbinding-vs-widgetsbinding-149c71cb607f) is some more detail on the differences.

Note: be sure to import the file needed for SchedulerBinding:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented as follows inside didChangeDependencies

```
 @override
void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    if (_isInit) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true;
      });
      Provider.of<Products>(context).fetchAndSetProducts().then((_) {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
      });
    }
    _isInit = false;
  }
```

Comment: As far as I understand, the problem with this is that you may end up rebuilding nested children that do not rely on data from Provider. So, within a widget that needs only some data once (not listening), if I were to use the `Consumer` it would potentially lead to wasted re-renders. In your example, the entire app is being re-rendered on every change of the Provider data.

Comment: I have edited my answer may this could help you

Comment: Your update to the question is the same mechanism of fetching data in the initialiser as what I have laid out in the question. The added business logic you've included even looks like it has been lifted directly from the tutorial that I have been following. I'm looking for an alternative to using a variable flag + `didChangeDependencies()`.

Answer (score 0):

you can have the Provider in a separate function and call that function within the `initState()`

```
bool isInit = true;

Future<void> fetch() async {
    await Provider.of<someProvider>(context, listen: false).fetch();
}

@override
  void initState() {
    if (isInit) {
      isInit = false;
      fetch();
    }
  isInit = false;
  super.initState();
    
}
```